# Expected Count to change by 1 but was changed by 0 - Pry within Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I had the following model: ExistingCustomer and all the tests were fine and it worked perfectly. Client requested a couple of new fields. One was a simple string so I updated. The other was an association with a specific region. Updated MVC and it works fine. It stores, etc.

However my rspec fails on create and I can't for the life of me figure out why/how to find the error.

So my spec looks like:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'pry'

RSpec.describe ExistingCustomersController, type: :controller do

  describe 'create' do
    it 'should create existing customer' do
      binding.pry
      expect do
        binding.pry
        post :create, params: { existing_customer: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:existing_customer) }
      end.to change(ExistingCustomer, :count).by(1)
    end
    it 'sends an email' do
      expect(ExistingCustomerMailer).to send_mail(:existing_customer_request)
      post :create, params: { existing_customer: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:existing_customer) }
    end
  end
end
```

FactoryBot looks like:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :existing_customer do
    region
    first_name { 'Jake' }
    last_name { 'Peralta' }
    phone { '991-999-9999' }
    email { 'best.detective@ninenine.com' }
    title { 'World\'s Best Detective/Genius' }
    account_number { 99 }
    company_name { 'NYPD' }
    existing_customer_email { 'better.detective@ninenine.com' }
  end
end
```

I've done both association :region and just region. No difference.
Instead of Factory I did something like:

let(:existing_params) do {first_name: 'Jake', etc}

And then passed that instead of FactoryBot. Same issue.

In all instances it's failing to create. How do I find out what's cause the issue with Pry. I know to insert binding.pry within the it block to access. What should I be grabbing within pry to test? I'm a rookie when it comes to pry testing within rspec.

EDIT:
So I put a binding.pry in the controller within the create:

```
def create
 @existing_customer = ExistingCustomer.new(existing_customer_params)
 binding.pry
 if @existing_customer.save
  redirect_to existing_customer_success_path
 ExistingCustomerMailer.existing_customer_request(@existing_customer).deliver
else
  render 'new'
end
```

end

Ran the test again and did @existing_customers.errors. It's returning @messages = :region=>{must exist}

So the question is how do I pass a particular association id within the params in the spec?

Comment: Pry pauses execution at a moment in time. The question then is: what do I want to know at that moment? The first two uses of pry pause before anything meaningful has happened. What about asking the count of existing customers, after the POST has occurred?

Comment: Valid point. So I did put a binding.pry after the expect before the closing end. Then I did ExistingCustomer.count and it's returning 0. So I guess in this case it's not creating.

Comment: Ok, next, run the post function in that Pry session. If a customer isn't being created, you should get an error in response. What is that error?

Comment: Updated. It looks like I need to find a way to pass in the test a particular associated id within the params.

Comment: You don't need to pass an ID, you need to provide a region. `region` in your exiting customer factory is referencing a region factory. Does such a factory exist?

Comment: It exists with a FactoryBot of name { 'String' } region_email { 'some@thing.com' } sequence(:position) { |n| n }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the attributes_for and the association with FactoryBot. This made the test pass:

```
it 'should create existing customer' do
  expect do
    post :create, params: { existing_customer: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:existing_customer)
                                                         .merge(region_id: create(:region)) }
  end.to change(ExistingCustomer, :count).by(1)
end
```